Cannot Render QMD File to HTML or DOCX with Quarto: "cannot open the connection" Error
I am working on a data report and when I try to render my QMD file to HTML or DOCX using Quarto, I encounter the following error:
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: .main -> execute -> write -> cat -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'Graphs.qmd': No such file or directory
Execution halted

I tried so many things, including specifying the full path to the file, creating a simple test file and render it, same error. I updated all my packages, reinstalled rtools, reinstalled quarto cli and the problem persists. I ran quarto check and all is "OK". I ran Rstudio as an admin to rule the permission problem out, it did not solve the problem. I ran the rendering commands from the command prompt and encountered the same issue.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)

I am really frustrated. I have been trying to figure this out since this morning. Thank you for any help trying to understand what is going on here.

I found a solution, see my answer, but if you have a proper solution that would prevent windows from doing this again, please share in the comments or add an answer below.

After so many hours of brainstorming, I remembered that on Saturday I updated my windows 11. So I disabled my windows defender to find whether quarto can write on my desk.
Indeed it worked.
If you are having the same issue I have, try the following (clearly, these steps are for windows users).:

windows key + i
go to privacy and security
click on "Open Windows Security"
on the left hand side panel, click Virus & Threat Protection.
find "manage settings" under Virus and Threat Protection Settings
Turn off Real Time protection.
go back to your RStudio and render your file.

If the above works, check the "exclusions" down below the page in step 5 and add Rstudio, Quarto and all other programming languages you have to that list.
Note:
After wasting so much time, I remembered how Windows sucks.
